# Can a father marry off his daughter for nissuin or only arusin?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, marriage, children-parenting

In the Torah a father is given the right to marry off his daughter before she's an adult. Does this work even for nissuin (the second stage of marriage) or only arusin?

Comment: How would a father effect nissuin?

Comment: @DoubleAATo To be honest i was wondering that myself. What I can't up with is that he 'allows' the biah with the husband. But that sounds horrible. The only reason I thought that is because of a rashi https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.40b.6 on this who seems to be saying that the father can marry off his daughter with biah.

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam Hilchot Ishut 10:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.10.16?lang=bi):

> המארס בתו קטנה, ותבעה הבעל לנישואין - בין היא בין אביה יכולין לעכב, שלא תינשא עד שתגדיל ותיעשה נערה.  ואם רצו וכנסה, כונס; ואין ראוי לעשות כן.‏
>
> One who effects *erusin* on behalf of his minor daughter, and the husband then wishes to perform *nissuin*, either the father or the daughter can prevent this from taking place, so that *nissuin* will not occur until she grows up and becomes a *na'arah*. But if they wish for him to perform *nissuin* he may; however it is not correct to do so.

Thus, the father has a veto over his minor daughter's *nissuin*, but he also cannot allow the *nissuin* to take effect against her will (unlike *erusin*).

In any event, Rambam rules that it's not proper to effect *nissuin* with a minor, even if all parties consent.

Comment: *Rambam rules that it's not proper to effect nissuin with a minor* - How about other great rabbis or fundamental Jewish texts ?

Comment: Tur (Even HaEzer 56) and Shulchan Aruch (Even HaEzer 56:4) both rule like Rambam

Comment: The *[Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4110.htm#16)* edition contains the plural form consistent with your quote.